# How to write a function that splits a string and converts it into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm trying to write a function that splits a string and converts it into a dictionary (and if possible, allows me to assign values to each string that's converted into a key). For instance, if I have sample input of `mystring = 'abcd'` I want to split this into individual letters, convert it into a dictionary and then assign each of the keys a given value (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4). So the sample output I'm looking for would be `{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}` I know that something like `enumerate()` is an effective way of converting a list into a dictionary, for instance:

```
dict(enumerate(mylist,1))
list_conversion = lambda x: dict(enumerate(x,1))
```

But I'm not sure how to do something similar for a string.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate because it's the exact same answer as your previous question (a string is a sequence just like a list so same function applies)

Answer (score 3):

Since strings are iterable the same way as lists, the exact same thing will work for strings:

```
>>> mystring = 'abcd' 
>>> dict(enumerate(mystring, 1))
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for such things is `Collections`
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html - python 2
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html - python 3

Default dict is a great way to handle things like creating key- values